# Firebase ios unable to get timestamp [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /serverTimestamp failed: permission_denied

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using this code

```
var currentTimeStamp: TimeInterval?

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("serverTimestamp")

    ref.setValue(ServerValue.timestamp())

    ref.observe(.value, with: { snap in

        if let t = snap.value as? Timestamp {
           // print(t/1000)
           // currentTimeStamp = t/1000

            //Add additional data(Timestamp) to list
            mutableData["timestamp"] = currentTimeStamp

            //FINALLY , set data
            newdoc.setData(mutableData) { (error) in
                completion(docID)
            }
        }
    })
```

got this error

```
Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /serverTimestamp failed: permission_denied
```

my rules set to Auth , but auth user still cant get the time stamp

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write the timestamp inside Firebase Realtime Database current structure is .

myproject [null] 
    |____ serverTimestamp : 1

Thought I have set the rules to complete public still cant get the timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules are set for the users node. You need to also specify rules for the "serverTimestamp" node.

```
    {
      "rules": {
        "users": {
           "$uid": {
              ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
              ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
           }
        },
        "serverTimestamp": {
           ".read": "auth_uid != null",
           ".write": "auth_uid != null"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is if you keep the structure the same.

When you specify rules in Firebase the term they use is atomic, you need to specify rules for each node and each sub node applies rules of the parent before applying their own. Your rules are only for the "$uid" node, you didn't specify any rules for "serverTimestamp" and since "serverTimestamp" doesn't fall under "$uid" permission is denied.

For example with your current permissions if you tried to read/write "users" node you will also get a permission denied. You can only access "users/($uid)/"